# Bug on getting the element width using vue3 ref

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I would like to ask what are your methods on getting the element width on vue3? I have used this style (image below), but it seems like there is something wrong with it. I can see the element width, but when I access it will give me different numbers. Any idea about this? Or any other method. Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

My Solution:

I tried using computed() in order to detect changes on the element. But I think computed cant detect the changes when you reference a variable ref to an element. But when I used the onUpdated lifehooks. This is where it is detected. So onUpdated solved it. Reference https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated

Computed code:

```
 const tableWidth = computed(() => {
       return tableRef?.value?.clientWidth
    })
```

OnUpdated code

```
  let tableWidth = ref()
    onUpdated(() => {
        tableWidth.value = document.getElementById('build-table').offsetWidth
    })
```

Comment: Do you have a reproduction example on CodeSandbox or similar platform?

Comment: probably just a side effect of logging object property vs logging full object.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects.  On mount the table might still be reactively updating itself and changing size, so the two different types of logs give two different widths